# CSS Skill Bar Animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to create a skill bar where the background color of the progress slides in but the label for the Skill bar stays in the same place.

```css
.skill-container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.skill-container {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skill-container .skill {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 4px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: #312E81;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  animation: animateLeft 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes animateLeft {
  from {
    left: -100%
  }
  to {
    left: 0
  }
}
.skill-container .skill.skill-level-70 {
  width: 70%
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-container">

  <span class="skill skill-level-70">CSS</span>

</div>
```

So far the animation works well, but the only thing I need to figure out is how to keep the text (CSS) on the left and animate the sliding of the background color to show the progress

Comment: Consider using the semantically correct [`<progress> element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) for an accessible progress bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pseudo element for the background:

```css
.skill-container .skill {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.skill-container .skill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #312E81;
  border-radius: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: animateLeft 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes animateLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.skill-container .skill.skill-level-70::before {
  width: 70%
}
.skill-container .skill.skill-level-40::before {
  width: 40%
}
.skill-container .skill.skill-level-100::before {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-container">
  <div class="skill skill-level-100">CSS</div>
  <div class="skill skill-level-70">HTML</div>
  <div class="skill skill-level-40">PHP</div>
</div>
```

You can optimize with CSS variables:

```css
.skill-container .skill {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.skill-container .skill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #312E81;
  border-radius: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:var(--l,0%);
  animation: animateLeft 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes animateLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-container">
  <div class="skill" style="--l:100%">CSS</div>
  <div class="skill" style="--l:70%">HTML</div>
  <div class="skill" style="--l:40%">PHP</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked a miracle. I need to start learning these before an dafte rpseodu classes now!